# ALT+CMD+R stopped working

Tags: eclipse, macos, keyboard, key, shortcut

I am using Mac and Eclipse. I used to use <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> for name refactoring. Unfortunatelly this key stopped working and using this key I write ® (only in Eclipse). <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> is still correctly defined in Keys section of Eclipse preferences. What could cause this strange behaviour?

Comment: Works fine for me. Did you upgrade anything? Are you in your usual perspective? Error message or nothing at all? Often, key shortcut work only in a couple perspectives.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps there is a conflict with other keybindings. Open up the binding view and in a unbinded command press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>. Check the conflicts section. If you can just see the "Rename-Refactoring /In Windows" you are fine.

Else search for "refactor" and then in the bind section of "Renaming-Refactoring" when "In Windows" clear everything and then press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>. Check for conflicts, clear them if any and then save.

Voila! you should be ready.

Answer (score 2):

try unbinding the key. Close the eclipse and bind it again. Or try to bind it with different key. Is all other shortcut keys work?

Comment: Thanks. Unbinding and restarting Eclipse didnt help. Binding to other keys works. And other shortcuts works well. Maybe installation of Aptana plugin caused this issue, but I think, it stopped working suddently during development :(

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and unbinding/rebinding did not work. However, uninstalling Aptana plugin fixed this issue right away.

Answer (score 1):

I've known Eclipse to occasionally lose key bindings.  Often undefining the binding and then reapplying it is enough to fix them.  In the worst case, you can export your key bindings, restore the default settings, and then import your bindings.  (Or, if you're using the defaults, just restore them and skip the import/export.)

Answer (score 0):

The Aptana Studio plugin may be the problem.

This problem started occurring for me after I installed Aptana Studio to try it out. I tried clearing and resetting the keybinding, and restarting Eclipse to no avail. Uninstalling Aptana Studio fixed the problem.